# Why does not JwtHeader offer a constructor that takes both SigningCredentials and EncryptingCredentials?

Tags: .net-core, cryptography, jwt

I am trying to construct JWT token using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt nuget package (version 5.4.0). It is .net standard 2.0 compliant and I am using .net core 2.2 for my project.

Under System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt namespace, I can find following method:

```
public virtual JwtSecurityToken CreateJwtSecurityToken(string issuer, string audience, ClaimsIdentity subject, DateTime? notBefore, DateTime? expires, DateTime? issuedAt, SigningCredentials signingCredentials, EncryptingCredentials encryptingCredentials);
```

I can use this method to supply both SigningCredentials and EncryptingCredentials. However I would like to use following code (for finer control) to create the json string.

```
var header = new JwtHeader(...);
var payload = new JwtPayload(...);
var t = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var json = handler.WriteToken(t);
```

To my surprise, I found that JwtHeader does not offer a constructor that takes  both SigningCredentials and EncryptingCredentials. All the constructors are shown below:

```
public JwtHeader();
public JwtHeader(SigningCredentials signingCredentials);
public JwtHeader(EncryptingCredentials encryptingCredentials);
public JwtHeader(SigningCredentials signingCredentials, IDictionary<string, string> outboundAlgorithmMap);
public JwtHeader(EncryptingCredentials encryptingCredentials, IDictionary<string, string> outboundAlgorithmMap);
```

Is there a reason why JwtHeader does not offer the constructor that takes both? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I’d assume that you can’t sign and encrypt a single message. You can encrypt a message, then wrap that in another message that’s signed; or the other way around. But since that’s two messages it would be two different headers. (All supposition, not actually familiar with JWT or the object model of this library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why JwtHeader does not provide a constructor that takes both SigningCredentials and EncryptingCredentials at the same time. At any given time, JwtHeader can be either JWS (JSON Web Signature) token or JWE (JSON Web Encryption) token. It can NOT be both at one time. If you want to sign and then encrypt, then the outer JWT will represent JWE whose nested token is of type JWS. If you want to encrypt and then sign, the outer JWT will be represent the JWS whose nested token is of type JWE.

If you need to validate the token that is first signed and then encrypted, you can use JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken method with both SigningCredentials as well as EncryptingCredentials at the same time to validate in one shot.

However if you need to validate the token that is first encrypted and then signed, you will have to use JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken method twice.

1. First with only SigningCredentials to validate the signature to retrieve the encrypted information (typically in form a claim).
2. Next you will have to use JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken again, this time with only EncryptingCredentials but providing the encrypted token string (retrieved from previous step).

This is why JwtSecurityTokenHandler can accept both SigningCredentials and EncryptingCredentials at the same time while the JwtHeader can not.

It would have been nice to have some documentation on how to use this API properly. I guess one has to read the standards on JWT, JWS and JWE.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519 (JWT)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515 (JWS)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516 (JWE)